# Dynamically adding child components to Canvas vs Group in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I've a custom component where I do some graphics (e.g draw a line) and dynamically add a subcomponent (e.g a label) to it.

If I base the component off Group (which is recommended as per docs since its a spark component) then when I dynamically add a label the graphics part disappears.

However if I base it off Canvas this doesn't happen.

Why is that the case?

Here is the code.

**MyComponent.as**

```
public class MyComponent extends Group
    {
        public var x1:int;
        public var y1:int;

        public function MyComponent()
        {
            super();

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
                x1 = mouseX;
                y1 = mouseY;
            });

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
                if (event.buttonDown) {
                    graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000);
                    graphics.moveTo(x1, y1)
                    graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
                    x1 = mouseX;
                    y1 = mouseY;
                }
            });
        }

        public function addLabel():void
        {
            var label:Label = new Label();
            label.x = 100;
            label.y = 100;
            label.text = "new label ";
            addElement(label);  //change to addChild if using Canvas 
        }
    }
```

**Main.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:local="*">

    <s:Panel width="50%" height="50%" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" title="Sample app">

        <MyComponent id="drawingArea" xmlns="*" width="100%" height="100%" />

        <s:controlBarContent>
            <s:Button label="Add label" click="drawingArea.addLabel()"/>
        </s:controlBarContent>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: We'll need to see the code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some additional insight:

http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/?p=296

Comment: Instead of linking to the answer, it's usually a better Idea to summarize (or reproduce, if the source material would permit) the key points that relate to the solution.  StackOverflow is meant to be a one-stop resource for programming questions, requiring users to leave the site to access the solution fails to meet that goal.

Comment: Thanks TokenMacGuy!  I'll be better at that going forward.  :)

Answer (score 0):

That is 'normal' as per how the component lifecycle works in Flex.  When an `invalidateDisplayList` gets called in your function, it redraws everything within it and clears the `graphics`.  When you add that label, it does invalidate.

If I were you, I'd do something like this:

```
public class MyComponent extends Group
{
    protected var _previousX:int;
    protected var _previousY:int;
    protected var _drawing:UIComponent;

    public function MyComponent()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
    }

    public function addLabel():void
    {
        var label:Label = new Label();
        label.x = 100;
        label.y = 100;
        label.text = "new label ";
        addElement(label);
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        if(!this._drawing)
        {
            this._drawing = new UIComponent();
            this._drawing.percentWidth = 100;
            this._drawing.percentHeight = 100;
            this.addElement(this._drawing);
        }
    }

    protected function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this._previousX = e.localX;
        this._previousY = e.localY;
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    }

    protected function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    }

    protected function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this._drawing.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000);
        this._drawing.graphics.moveTo(this._previousX, this._previousY);
        this._drawing.graphics.lineTo(e.localX, e.localY);
        this._previousX = e.localX;
        this._previousY = e.localY;
    }
}
```

This is untested, but I think you get the idea.  You should also read up on component lifecycles and really think about what behavior that you're trying to accomplish by trying to abstract it as data (I'm not a fan of the 'addLabel' function for instance :P).